# How can i catch Container exceptions?

Tags: laravel, exception, ioc-container

I want to be able to catch container binding exceptions but it doesn't seem to work.

If i have this code:

```
try {
    $instance = app()->make('SomeNonExistingBinding');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle failure
}
```

But somehow the thrown Exception is being caught in the `Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline::prepareDestination()` method that AFAIK converts the exceptions in HTTP responses, instead of my `try-catch` block.

Can someone help me on this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't catch container exceptions. There shouldn't be missing registrations. You should register Null Object implementations in case there isn't a 'real' implementation.

Comment: where is this code running? is there a namespace declared?

Comment: I'm writing a simple (namespaced, of course) psr/container adapter. The spec clearly states the container should throw a ContainerException in case of error. So, basically, i want to throw a NotFoundException in case of binding failure and a ContainerException in all other error conditions.